# Increasing padding of a box increases the height of the table row it's in

Tags: html, css

I'm making a table containing some marks, which have a box around them. When you hover over the box, the mark needs to expand in size a little bit to show that it's active. This is my code:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mark_table {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#mark_table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  max-height: 39px;
  height: 20px;
}

#mark_table .spacer {
  width: 100%;
}

#mark_table th {
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#mark_table .rotate_th {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mark_table .rotate {
  transform: rotate(285deg);
  padding: 0;
}

#mark_table .table_header {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mark_wrapper {
  text-align: left;
}

.mark {
  background-color: #00C853;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mark:hover {
  padding: 1px;
}

.mark a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <table id="mark_table">

    <tr class="table_header">
      <th>Vakken</th>
      <th>Cijfers</th>
      <th class="spacer"></th>
      <th class="rotate_th">
        <div class="rotate">Rapport Gem.</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate_th">
        <div class="rotate">Rapport Cijfer</div>
      </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    
  </table>
</div>
```

The .mark class contains the mark. As you can see, whenever you hover over one of them its padding increases, but it increases the height of the row and moves the other marks to the right a little bit.

I need the row height to stay the same, and the other marks to stay in the same position. Keep in mind that whenever too many marks are added, they need to jump to the next line.

I tried adding a max-height to the mark_wrapper, but that prevents marks from jumping to the next line, and makes the mark only increase in height on the bottom.

Comment: tried using `table-layout: fixed`?

Comment: @bowl0stu yes, but that messes up the entire layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding padding, add scaling effect to mark on hover

```
.mark:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mark_table {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#mark_table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  max-height: 39px;
  height: 20px;
}

#mark_table .spacer {
  width: 100%;
}

#mark_table th {
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#mark_table .rotate_th {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mark_table .rotate {
  transform: rotate(285deg);
  padding: 0;
}

#mark_table .table_header {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mark_wrapper {
  text-align: left;
}

.mark {
  background-color: #00C853;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mark:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.mark a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <table id="mark_table">

    <tr class="table_header">
      <th>Vakken</th>
      <th>Cijfers</th>
      <th class="spacer"></th>
      <th class="rotate_th">
        <div class="rotate">Rapport Gem.</div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate_th">
        <div class="rotate">Rapport Cijfer</div>
      </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subject">
        <span title="Nederlandse taal en cultuur">netl</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="mark_wrapper">
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
          <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X.X</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="final">
        <div class="mark"><a href="#">X</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @GautamNaik I was going to, but it told me to wait five minutes. Accepted it now

Answer (score 0):

My solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwtbq9n3/).

As an alternative to scaling the marks, you can also remove some *margin* when adding extra *padding*. So when you add `1px` of extra padding, you remove `1px` of margin at the same time, so you see no difference in the space around your marks. (The original margin is `5px`, on hover the top and bottom margin will become `4px` to counter the extra padding, and the left and right margin will stay the same `5px`.)

```
.mark:hover {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 4px 5px;
}
```

To help with the overall spacing/sizing, also add this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you want to know more about the *box-model* and this specific usage of it, I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEfH6qnFF6Y), it helped me a lot.

Comment: I think the scaling effect is a better solution too, but I would still appreciate an upvote ;) Dankjewel!

Comment: I have upvoted you, just don't have 15 rep. yet so it doesn't show. Graag gedaan :)